# Daneil 9:27 syntax question

Tags: grammar, syntax

I am not looking for any specific interpretation, concerning the fulfillment of this scripture, just want to know if when it says in the middle of the week, has to be the middle of the week previously mentioned "and he shall confirm a covenant with many for 1 week?

> Dan 9:27 - And he will confirm a covenant with many for one week, but
> **in the middle of the week** he will put an end to sacrifice and offering. And on the wing of the temple will come the abomination that
> causes desolation, until the decreed destruction is poured out upon
> him.”

Comment: The prophecy of the 70 weeks has a huge literature.  Such literature is divided along theological line depending on the exegete's pre-suppositions - whether futurist, historicist, preterist, etc.  I suggest you examine some of this material.  In the mean time, please be more specific about what sytax question you are asking.

Comment: The Hebrew literally says, "in the half of the week", namely the 70th week.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my overly literal translation of Dan 9:27.

> And he shall confirm covenant with many [for] one week; but half [of]
> the week he shall end sacrifice and offering; and on wing [of]
> abominations ...

Notice that the half of the week refers (via the article "the") back to the 'one week" immediately previous.  That is, the half/middle of the week is anaphoric to the week just mentioned.

Comment: Is there in any way that the art. Can be referring to a theme in the book ,instead of always having to refer to the previous verse,are you Aware of this usage?

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - the grammar demands that it refer NOT to a theme but that which immediately previous.

Comment: I mean could what was previous mentioned be a close subject rather than a word. Like the final week, because some will say that he will confirm a covenant for one week, in the middle of "the" week.. now "the" could it be referring to the 70th week previously mentioned, and the confirming of a week, is a week previous to "the" week, not "the" week being the same as the "a" week he shall confirm.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - now you are asking another question about which week Messiah confirmed the covenant with Israel.  That should be the subject of another question.

Comment: I am asking what make the be the same as a, simplest way of saying it. Could the confirmation of the week be a different week than the middle of the week. Is there any way in rules of Hebrew to allow this interpretation.  Like talking about 10.5 instead of 3.5

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - not really.

Comment: Well how about sir Robert Anderson coming prince, he interprets the people of the prince to come, to be some one different than the prince previously mentioned. His work was accepted under much peer review.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150548/discussion-between-thatwemaybethepraiseofhisglory-and-dottard).